# Pyglet: How to let sprite instances of same class share coordinates?

Tags: python, class, pyglet

How do you make this code work: Just have pyglet installed and change `assassin1.png`,`assassin2.png` and `assassin3.png` with the name of images stored in the directory where you saved this code to a file.

```
import pyglet

def sprite_type(type_ = "standing"):
    if type_ == "moving-forward":
        moving_forward_image_list = [pyglet.image.load('assassin2.png'), pyglet.image.load('assassin3.png')]
        moving_forward_animation = pyglet.image.Animation.from_image_sequence(moving_forward_image_list, 0.3) 
        return moving_forward_animation
    if type_ == "standing":
        standing_animation = pyglet.image.load("assassin1.png")
        return standing_animation

class Assassin(pyglet.sprite.Sprite):        
    def __init__(self, batch, img):
        pyglet.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, img, x = 50, y = 30)

class Game(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        pyglet.window.Window.__init__(self, width = 315, height = 220)
        self.batch_draw = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
        self.player_dict = {"standing": Assassin(batch = self.batch_draw, img = sprite_type()), "moving-forward": Assassin(batch = self.batch_draw, img = sprite_type(type_ = "moving-forward"))}
        self.player = self.player_dict["standing"]
        self.fps_display = pyglet.clock.ClockDisplay()
        self.keys_held = []      
        self.schedule = pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(func = self.update, interval = 1/60.) 

    def on_draw(self):
        self.clear()
        self.fps_display.draw()
        self.batch_draw.draw()
        self.player.draw()  

    def on_key_press(self, symbol, modifiers):
        self.keys_held.append(symbol)
        if symbol == pyglet.window.key.RIGHT:
            self.player = self.player_dict["moving-forward"]
            print "The 'RIGHT' key was pressed"

    def on_key_release(self, symbol, modifiers):
        self.keys_held.pop(self.keys_held.index(symbol))
        self.player = self.player_dict["standing"]

    def update(self, interval):
        if pyglet.window.key.RIGHT in self.keys_held:
            self.player.x += 50 * interval

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = Game()
    pyglet.app.run()
```

This code displays `assassin1.png` while no key is held at position (50 30), when the right key is held the character moves forward and every 0.3 seconds the 2 images `assassin2.png` and `assassin3.png` are switched as to give the illusion of a walking character. Also the fps are shown.

**Currently when you release the  key the character will return to the original position (50, 30). When you press the  key again the character moves from the position where the walking character stopped last.**

**I understand why this happens because the walking animation character and the standing character are two different instances of the same class. 
I first thought using class variables I would be able to store the position. But I can't seem to come up with a working solution. Does anyone have any ideas what I could do?**

### Edit 1 (@Hugh Bothwell)

```
import pyglet

def sprite_type(type_ = "standing"):
    if type_ == "moving-forward":
        moving_forward_image_list = [pyglet.image.load('assassin2.png'), pyglet.image.load('assassin3.png')]
        moving_forward_animation = pyglet.image.Animation.from_image_sequence(moving_forward_image_list, 0.3) 
        return moving_forward_animation
    if type_ == "standing":
        standing_animation = pyglet.image.load("assassin1.png")
        return standing_animation

class Assassin(pyglet.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, batch, img):
        pyglet.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, img, x = 50, y = 30)

    def stand(self, batch, img):
        self.batch = batch
        self.img = img

    def move(self, batch, img):
        self.batch = batch
        self.img = img      

class Game(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        pyglet.window.Window.__init__(self, width = 315, height = 220)
        self.batch_draw = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
        self.player = Assassin(batch = self.batch_draw, img = sprite_type())
        self.fps_display = pyglet.clock.ClockDisplay()
        self.keys_held = []      
        self.schedule = pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(func = self.update, interval = 1/60.) 

    def on_draw(self): 
        self.clear()         
        self.fps_display.draw()
        self.batch_draw.draw()
        self.player.draw()  

    def on_key_press(self, symbol, modifiers):
        self.keys_held.append(symbol)
        if symbol == pyglet.window.key.RIGHT:
            self.player.move(batch = self.batch_draw, img = sprite_type("moving-forward"))
            # if I put the following line here instead:
            #self.player = self.player.move(batch = self.batch_draw, img = sprite_type("moving-forward"))
            # I get this error when pressing the <right-direction> key:
            #self.player.draw(), AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'draw'
            print "The 'RIGHT' key was pressed"

    def on_key_release(self, symbol, modifiers):
        self.keys_held.pop(self.keys_held.index(symbol))
        self.player.stand(batch = self.batch_draw, img = sprite_type("standing"))

    def update(self, interval):
        if pyglet.window.key.RIGHT in self.keys_held:
            self.player.x += 50 * interval

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = Game()
    pyglet.app.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having a standing-character and a walking-character, you need one character who has a movement-state.

Comment: I added a move and stand method. But now my character doesn't show the walking animation anymore when he moves. Could you take a look at my edit please?